# Working around with form load events

Tags: c#, combobox

Is there any way to avoid form.activate or form.load for the first time?? I have a button in the main form which opens a new form to in which i enter a name..this name is aded to a db . the main form contains a combobox which lists all names added to the db. now.. i need to update the combobox data when a new name is added..

As FORM1 is my main form, i need to keep my combobox updated there also.. so i have called the method that update the cmbobox in the init call..

but this doesnt update the box when a new name is added.. when i call the method in formload event, the combobox shows repeated entries ..

this is my code..

```
  private void listdata() 
    {
        SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection(str);
        a.Open();
        SqlCommand b = new SqlCommand();
        b.Connection = a;
        b.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        b.CommandText = "getname"; 
        SqlDataAdapter c = new SqlDataAdapter(b);
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        c.Fill(d);

        foreach (DataRow m in d.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn n in d.Columns)
            {
                lst_name.Items.Add(m[n].ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

this im calling in init of the main form... i need the data in the combobox when the main form loads..

then when a add button is clicked;

```
NewEntry x = new NewEntry();
        x.ShowDialog();
```

this form called newentry adds data to a db which is used to populate the combobox on the main form.

now i need the combobox on the main form to be updated  when the "newentry" form closes..(meaning new data is entered into the db)

Comment: Probably, if you add the code that shows this interaction between the two forms, your question will be more comprehensible.

Comment: Do you mean that you have 2 Forms and wants to Load Form2 at First, without loading Form1?

Comment: This question is incredibly confusing. Why can't you just put the code in the `Form1.Activate` event handler? That way, it runs then the form is first displayed, *and* when it is re-activated upon closing Form2.

Comment: @Steve Edited the quest. do chk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is the flow of events in your situation.
But a simple answer to your double items problem could be a simple

```
    lst_name.Items.Clear();
```

before running the loop that inserts the names

```
    foreach (DataRow m in d.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn n in d.Columns)
        {
            lst_name.Items.Add(m[n].ToString());
        }
    }
```